# Understanding Impedence when modifying a spring reverb

Tags: resistance, instrumentation-amplifier

So I found this [spring reverb tank](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BGXW50) on Amazon for $17. I understanding that it is supposed to be used inside a guitar amp but I want to see if I can modify it to be a low-cost spring reverb for use with my keyboards. It says it has an Input Impedance of 800 Ohms and an Output Impedance of 2,575 Ohms. Would I be able to run the output of my keyboard into the input of the reverb and then just run the output of the reverb into an XLR mic input on my mixer to amplify the signal back to the proper level? Or would running the output through a DI box be better? I am not sure how the ohms relate to the instrument signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I be able to run the output of my keyboard into the input of the
>   reverb and then just run the output of the reverb into an XLR mic
>   input on my mixer to amplify the signal back to the proper level?

That *would* work but it would sound awful. The reason why is that a spring reverb is just the pure "reverb" section of the overall sound a musician would expect. Typically the output from the spring would be mixed with the original sound at a level of maybe 5% to 10% - that would then produce a "reasonable" reverb sound.

So you will need an op-amp mixer on the output to subtley mix the spring output with the original sound. This now means you have a powered output buffer and you might as well use a powered input buffer to drive the spring and thus present a more reasonable impedance to your keyboard's output signal.

Comment: Right, I have an 8-channel mixer I play through and so I could direct the AUX send to the spring reverb and then run the reverb output through a DI box back into AUX return and use that level to mix it with the rest of the sound.

Comment: Update: I got the spring reverb and used it with the mixer as I said and it works well.

Comment: @Rozgonyi excellent news.